# Chrome Dev Editor Using Bower and Highcharts Shim

Tags: javascript, highcharts, google-chrome-app, bower, polymer

I am working on setting up a polymer web app in the [Chrome Dev Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-dev-editor-develop/pnoffddplpippgcfjdhbmhkofpnaalpg?hl=en). The `bower.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "HighchartsTest",
  "description": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "keywords": [
  ],
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#master",
    "core-elements": "Polymer/core-elements#master"
  }
```

I am having trouble getting bower to pull down the highcharts shim (or the highstock). I thought I could do this format:

```
{
  "name": "HighchartsTest",
  "description": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "keywords": [
  ],
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#master",
    "core-elements": "Polymer/core-elements#master",
    "highstock-release": "js/highstock-release"
  }
```

However this just creates a directory under `bower_components` called `highstock-release` but it only contains a `.git` directory with no actual source code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want "highslide-software/highstock-release"

In your bower config, the dependencies are in "github syntax", so they are expanded to "git://github.com/highslide-software/highstock-release", etc.

Comment: Which part of that should be the expanded name? The key: or value?

Comment: The value should have that string. The key is the name of the folder that will get have the value's contents.

A good mental model is "foo": "bar/baz" -> git clone git://github.com/bar/baz.git bower_components/foo

Comment: Excellent! First time using bower.